# Nodelet is not recognized as a plugin

Tags: ros-groovy, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to do the plugin tutorial, but `rospack plugin --attrib` didn't recognize my plugin.  So I decided to move on to nodelets with plugins and I get the same problem.  Here is my nodelet class:

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>

namespace nodeletnamespace {

    class mynodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet {
        public:
            virtual void onInit();
    };

    void mynodelet::onInit() {
        ROS_INFO("[%s] initialized.", getName().c_str());
    }
}    

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(nodeletnamespace::mynodelet, nodelet::Nodelet)
```

Here is mynodelet.xml:

```
<library path="lib/libmynodelet">
    <class name="nodelet_test/mynodelet"
        base_class_type ="nodelet::Nodelet"
        type="nodeletnamespace::mynodelet">
    <description>My Nodelet class </description>
    </class>
</library>
```

Here is the package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>nodelet_test</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The nodelet_test package</description>

  <maintainer email="jzt0011@auburn.edu">jt</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nodelet</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>nodelet</run_depend>


  <export>
    <nodelet plugin="${prefix}/mynodelet.xml" />
  </export>
</package>
```

and here is the Cmakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(nodelet_test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS nodelet roscpp)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES nodelet_test
   CATKIN_DEPENDS nodelet roscpp
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(lib_mynodelete src/mynodelet.cpp)
```

any help is appreciated!

Here is the error I get:
rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone /nodelet_test/nodeletnamespace __name:=bro
type is /nodelet_test/nodeletnamespace
[ERROR] [1371234670.671631285]: Failed to load nodelet [/bro] of type [/nodelet_test/nodeletnamespace]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class /nodelet_test/nodeletnamespace with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_test/mynodelet nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus pcl/BAGReader pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65189/nodelet-is-not-recognized-as-a-plugin/) by [kaoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5069/kaoao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*First, please add the full error message and put it in the right formatting.*

Here are a few things I noticed in your problem description:

Does your library build at all? I see the missing dependency on pluginlib.

I see a spelling mistake in your CMakeLists.txt: add_library(lib_mynodelet**e** src/mynodelet.cpp)

Finally, please make sure that the below really points to your xml file.

```
<export>
  <nodelet plugin="${prefix}/mynodelet.xml" />
</export>
```

Hope this helps!

PS: This is the command, which lists all the available nodelet plugins:

`rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nodelet`

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1